# nested templated struct instantiation in d2

Tags: templates, struct, d

I am trying to put one struct template into the other with a Type `T` as a parameter. I have to pass `T` to the inner struct, but can't since I can only have one `!` in my template defenition.

```
struct foo(T)
{
    qux!bar!T myBar;
}

struct bar(T)
{
    // do something with T.
}

struct qux(T)
{
    // do something with T;
}
```

What is the syntactically correct to try to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use parens to disambiguate instantiation order:

```
struct foo(T)
{
    qux!(bar!T) myBar;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I'll mark this as solved in 4 minutes when the timer lets me.